# R Studio - How to change the name of a dataframe in a script by one click?

Tags: r, dataframe, rstudio, filenames, renaming

I have a pretty simple question, I googled it, but I cant find anything, probably I am using the wrong words.

I am using R-Studio and I want to change the name of my dataframe for my whole script. I used that name 20-30 times and I dont want to change everything manually. I remember that our teacher showed us a trick once. When you click on the name of the dataframe you want to change, every entry in the script is marked with a blue window.

How does that work? What do I have to do that I can rename all these entries by changing only one of them?

Comment: I think you are referring to the "rename in scope" feature [demonstrated in a gif in this post](https://rviews.rstudio.com/2016/11/11/easy-tricks-you-mightve-missed/) - though it looks like it takes two or three clicks. In general, this isn't really a programming question - I would suggest asking questions about RStudio features on the RStudio help forums.

Comment: Yes, perfect, thank you so much! Sorry, I didnt know that this site here is only for programming.

Comment: Stop writing scripts and start writing functions. Then you pass the dataframe you want to work with as an argument to your function, and your code can work with *any* dataframe without modification.